# How to identify the loop (for, foreach, while & do-while) in dll level by the (FxCop) Introspector & Code written in C# language

Tags: c#, fxcop, rule

How to separate the (for, foreach, while & do-while) loop part alone in dll level of the (FxCop) Introspector & Code written in C# language.
**Rule details:**
1)  I need to identify the loop.
2)  And then I need to find the how many objects are instantiated inside the loop.
3)  In the introspector i identified the loops in the “block” (dll -> Types ->  Class Name -> Member -> Method Name -> Body=), under the block statement using the key word “branch”. 
4)  But my problem is for a simple for loop, “branch” keyword & for loop contents are repeating more than one time.

```
Eg:
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) 
{
             StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
}
```

Comment: What makes you think they will be accurately differentiable? I expect that there are heuristics which will be valid for *most* of the time, but I expect I could write a `while` loop that ends up with the same IL as the C# compiler generates for a `for` loop...

Comment: @JonSkeet, Thanks for your kind reply.  Normally using the Introspector the call method & statements are easy to differentiateby using Block (body="block"). But In loops case all loops looks almost same in the IL level &  its making hard to identify (differentiate) the loops.And in If case (conditional statement) also use key word "Branch" in the Block (body="block"). So I need to differentiate the loops from the Conditional statement. if any body knows the solution for this issue then share it

Comment: That's my point: if the loops result in the same IL, how do you expect it to be even feasible? Even if they aren't exactly the same IL, I'd expect different compilers to possibly have *very slightly* different output. Basically, I don't think it's going to be feasible.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for your reply. But there should be a possible way to do it. If anybody the solution to this issue please share your idea.

Comment: Why should there be a possible way to do it? How *could* there be, if the generated IL is the same?

Comment: @Jonseet Thanks for your reply. Because Machine should be under the looping concept so that the Microsoft programmer  should have some way to understand the logic of loops.  For example the jetbrains dotpeek is decoding the code concept by using the dll (How do they did it?). so they have some logic to do it.

Comment: What makes you think DotPeek will always be able to get it right, every time? IL has no concept of "for", "foreach" or "while" - and has no reason to. Basically, it sounds like you're translating "I would like the compiler's transformation to be reversible" into "The compiler's transformation should be reversible" and I don't think that's valid. I believe that "You should be able to decompile IL to the original C#" is part of the design of IL or the C# compiler.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for your response. and sorry for the way i conveyed the message. Here my point is if the machine are able to understands the logic of loops then we can also follow  the same method to understand those logic.

Comment: That doesn't mean you can necessarily get back to the original loop type. Two loops of different types can behave the exact same way, and be represented by the same IL. The CLR doesn't care which loop type was in the source code.

Comment: @jonSkeet  Thanks for your response. Correct me if my under standing is wrong.  We can't differentiate the loop statements & condition statement. from branch statement in the IL level. if i need to do the differentiation then i need to go with structure oriented rule creating tools (like: stylecop)

Comment: Sort of. If you care about what you see in source code, that's what you should be analyzing - you might want to look at Roslyn analyzers.